# Print all the tags from a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, tags

I need to print all the tags links which i used in custom post type.

Name of Custom post type= mobile

Taxonomy tag slug =  brand

```
<?php 
  $terms = get_terms( 'brand' );
  $count = count( $terms );
   if ( $count > 0 ) {
      echo '<ul>';
      foreach ( $terms as $term ) {?>

      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo '<p>' . $term->name . '</p>';?> </a>

 <?php }
  echo '</ul>';
}?>
```

With this code i successfully print all tags name. But unable to make these links.

**How to print tags with link to view all post related to that tag??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the link of any term meta, use `get_term_link()` function. 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/

So replace `the_permalink()` to `echo get_term_link($term->term_id);` inside your loop.

```
<a href="<?php  echo get_term_link($term->term_id); ?>"><?php echo '<p>' . $term->name . '</p>';?> </a>
```

This link will redirect to tag archive page.
Hope this help!